# How to create an IO object for Aws::S3::Object to stream d/l line by line?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Ruby novice here. I'd like to stream a large S3 object (text file) and process it line at a time. I don't want to store the object data locally or load it fully in memory. [`Aws::S3::Object#get()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#get-instance_method) takes a hash whose `response_target` parameter can take an IO object but I am unsure how to subclass or instantiate an `IO` instance to do what I want.

I'd like to end up with something like:

```rb
line_reader = nil # TODO make my IO instance

s3_obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')
s3_obj.get({response_target: line_reader}) # returns as soon as streaming begins?

# line_reader does not accumulate response data in memory
line_reader.each do | text_line | 
  # do processing on each line independently
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to use IO.new?
Also, if you want to change behavior of IO - you always can inheritance from it
`class MyIO < IO`

Comment: Please read "[ask]", including the links, and "[mcve]". While we love helping, we want to see what you tried, rather than fill in your blank section. SO isn't a "write code for me", it's a "we'll help you fix your broken code" site. Show us what you wrote toward solving the problem, and, if you haven't written anything, why not?

Comment: @АлексейКузнецов I guess I am unsure how to use IO class in this case. Should I use `IO.pipe`? Should I subclass `IO` and override which methods? Something else?

Answer (score -1):

Acording to [streaming_data_to_a_block](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/ef9f2d3655c4bacb3adff580a6b295df510f78fe/doc-src/examples/s3/client/get_object/03_streaming_data_to_a_block.rb) you could stream data from s3 object like this:

```
s3.get_object(bucket: 'bucket-name', key: 'object-key') do |chunk|
  # process chunk of data
end
```